# Search files into a directory / compatible Unix / Windows

Tags: python

i'm a beginner in Python, and try to use the os module to find and aggregate all files in a given folder, given a key word such as "example".

Based on what I found so far, here is my code :

```
def import_files_list(path, key_word):
files = []
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and key_word in i:
        file_plus_path = path+i
        pprint(file_plus_path)
        files.append(file_plus_path)
return files

actual_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
wanted_dir = os.path.split(actual_dir)[0]
files_list = import_files_list(wanted_dir, 'example') 
pprint(files_list)
```

The thing is that, instead of getting for instance :

```
'C:\\Users\\User\\folder\\example1.csv'
```

I'm getting :

```
'C:\\Users\\User\\folderexample1.csv'
```

So this is not correct.

I don't want to hardcode anything such as "\" to solve the problem, and I'm pretty sure I could also simplify the above code.

Could you help me and tell me here I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
    file_plus_path = path+i
```

Here you append one string to another, but without any delimiter between them.  On the previous line you did it correctly: `os.path.join(path,i)`.

So here's a way to correct that:

```
file_plus_path = os.path.join(path,i)
if os.path.isfile(file_plus_path) and key_word in i:
    pprint(file_plus_path)
    files.append(file_plus_path)
```